How to connect docking station USB-C to PC with no USB-C port?
I bought a docking station with USB-C input but one of my computers has no USB-C port.
Considering this docking station is compatible with 3 screens (2xHDMI+DP), 6 USB ports and PD of 100W, I imagine this input USB-C is quite powerful and requires a good setup.
My need is to connect this docking station to a PC with no USB-C and separated USB 3.0  + HDMI + DP ports for a 2 meters distance (6.56 feets).
So, I think this PC does not support this docking in this way and the distance may be a problem.
What should I do ?
For now, my best option is to buy a PCI Express extension for USB-C with a 100w USB-C cable, but I am not sure this is enough. There is a risk I missed a requirement.
Is there any technology to connect my graphic card to this docking station ? (To support video games)

If you have a USB 3.1 or 3.2 port then get an USB3 to USBC adaptor.
But if the system is old or does not have the ability to take a PCI express card you may need to swap the graphics card instead for the the extra monitors, and buy monitors with built in USB.
